# Hub control Background sometimes not drawn or drawn incorrectly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) app that has a Page and on that page there is a Hub control. My intention is to set an image as the background of the Hub because I like the cool animation when swiping through the HubSections.

I do this with the following XAML:

```
<Hub>
    <Hub.Background>
        <ImageBrush
            ImageSource="{Binding Images.Fanart}"
            Stretch="UniformToFill"
            Opacity="0.3">
        </ImageBrush>
    </Hub.Background>

    <!-- here come some hub sections with content -->
</Hub>
```

As you can see, the Background is set to be an ImageBrush. This brush has the ImageSource property bound to Images.Fanart, which is an ImageSource class in my data model:

```
public Images
{
    private ImageSource _fanart;

    public ImageSource Fanart
    {
        get { return _fanart; }
        private set
        {
            if (_fanart != value)
            {
                _fanart = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(); // Note: notification works properly
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my intention is to download images from the web and set them as the Fanart:

```
Fanart = new BitmapImage(new Uri("{the_image_url}", UriKind.Absolute));
```

This downloading and setting is done when the page is navigated to (OnNavigatedTo event).

**Now the actual problem:**

- Sometimes this works properly and the image is loaded and behaves/animates correctly when swiping through the hub sections.
- However, sometimes the image does not show up at all, although debugging reveals that the Fanart property has been refreshed.
- And sometimes, the image is shown, but it is animated in a wrong way. It is not drawn in its full width and it seems that its left margin is not mapped to the left margin of the first hub section.

This is pretty annoying and I wonder what I'm doing wrong. Maybe this is also a bug in the Hub Control?